# Got 'argument 1 is empty error' with selectInput in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app like below using `diamonds` dataset as an example. I'm using two selectInput as data filter. The first one select a variable. The second one shows the values, depending on the variable selected in the first selectInput. After selection, click the actionButton to trigger the filter. Without any variable and value selected, I want it output the whole dataset.

What I found is after I clear the two selectInput and then click the actionButton,  I got error: `argument 1 is empty`.  I do not understand why that happens. Spent hours but unable to find the solution. Do anyone know how I can fix it?  Thanks a lot!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

data(diamonds)

df = diamonds[1:1000,]

subset_data = function(data,
                       var=NULL,
                       value=NULL){

    if (!is.null(var)) {
        if(!is.null(value)) {
            data = data %>% filter(!!sym(var) == value)
        }
    }

    return(data)
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "example"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(


            selectizeInput(inputId = 'var', 
                           label='Select variable',
                           choices = c('cut', 'color'), 
                           multiple=FALSE,
                           options = list(
                               maxItems = 1,
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I("function() { this.setValue(''); }"))),

            uiOutput("valueUI"),
            actionButton('go', 'apply filter'),

            tableOutput('table')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$valueUI = renderUI({

        if (input$var == '') {
            vals = '' 
        }
        if (input$var == 'cut') {
            vals = c('Premium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair')  
        }
        if (input$var == 'color'){
            vals = c('E', 'J', 'I', 'H')
        }

        selectizeInput(inputId = 'value', 
                       label='Select values',
                       choices = c('',vals), 
                       multiple=FALSE,
                       options = list(
                           maxItems = 1,
                           placeholder = '',
                           onInitialize = I("function() { this.setValue(''); }")))

    })

    dat = reactive({
        input$go

        isolate( subset_data(data=df, var=input$var, value=input$value) )
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        dat()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "after I clear the two selectInput and then click the actionButton". I ran the app and it seemed to work without error. I selected "cut" and "very good" then clicked "apply filter". I then changed it to "good" and it still worked. What do you mean by clearing them? How do you reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `input$var` not given, it will be handled with `''` as you implemented.

However, in same time it will also give parameter `var` value in  `subset_data` function as `''` not `NULL`, so it will be not recognized with `!is.null(var)` and trigger `filter` for `data` .

You can see these explanation if you change subset_data like below code;

```
subset_data = function(data,
                       var=NULL,
                       value=NULL){
  print('var:')
  print(var) # var is given as ''
  print("value:")
  print(value)
  if (!is.null(var)) {
    if(!is.null(value)) {
      print('hi')
      data = data %>% filter(!!sym(var) == value)
      print('hi2') # this will not printed, since filter makes error.
    }
  }

  return(data)
}
```

so in this case, you can fix them with adding just 1 line on subset_data to check if `var == ''`.

```
if( var == '' ) return(data)
```

Regards.

Comment: I added the line but it still gives the same error message.  @jhk0530

Comment: Can you tell me how did you added? because it worked on my machine, so if you tell that, it will be helpful to find problem.

Comment: `if (var=='') {return (data)}` I added this line right above `return (data)`

Comment: I then cleared both selectInput and click actionbutton, I got the same error message

Comment: No you should add before check `is.null(var)`, it will change `data` as **filtered**.